# Does Facebook graph API provides friends addresses?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When Facebook graph API provides friends list of an person. Does it provides addresses of the friends Or the place where they are living ? If yes please point me to online documentation or article. I searched lot but nothing found for addresses of friends.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't! The `friends_*` have been removed with Graph API v2.0 on 2014-04-30.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_login